# How do I get a full list of members of a discord server using python?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I try to get a full list of members for the server that the bot is in, but I only end up getting the bot information.

Here is what I was doing.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('-members'):
    for guild in client.guilds:
      for member in guild.members:
        print(member)
```

Comment: Are you looking for all members in every guild or just the members in one guild? [`client.get_all_members()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_all_members) will get every member in all guilds and [`Guild.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members) gets all members in one guild

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#intents)

You need [`discord.Intents.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.members) set to `True` in order to get the information you seek.

---

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents = intents)
```